# cordova failed to load 3rd layer page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

i am developing simple apps with cordova, jquery mobile.
**First page is index.html :**

- -contain welcome message and list of products.

**Second page is product.html :**

- contain detail of product (if i click a product in index.html)
- contain of related products (if i click one of them, it ll be link to
  same page/product.html

here is the structure.

[image]

my problem is, when i click one of related product, it ll not display anything.

i put all javascript on index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SocialSharing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if `onclick` event relies on your scripts and your scripts are not included in product.html they won't work - note this also applies to jQuery. Include relevant script links in your second page and you should be fine.

Comment: no..i am not using onclik, but <a href="product.html?id=' + data.product_id + ' ">

Comment: and how are you accessing passed arguments? are you using javascript to parse the url of the landing page? seeing the code would sure make things easier to debug.